# Is it possible to clone a Vuejs property on set?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vuejs component that edits various properties of its value object and emits an input event with a new object when things change. I don't want to modify the value object itself so I copy properties into data and I have essentially the same code in a watch on value to update them when the value changes.

It would be very much simpler if the value could just be cloned when set. Is there any way to do this? I know I can do this in the "calling" component but it shouldn't have to do that.

Example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-checkbox label="Indoor" v-model="value.indoor" @change="onChange"/>
    <v-checkbox label="Outdoor" v-model="value.outdoor" @change="onChange"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'OptionsInput',

    props: {
      value: Object, // has indoor, outdoor properties
    },

    methods: {
      onChange() { this.$emit('input', this.value) }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I don't want to modify value directly.

Comment: You can user JSON.parse and JSON.stringify

Comment: @HelderLucas that method is not recommended for deep cloning, because it destroys some data (It does not support `undefined` values and `function()`). So it's better to use libraries or a custom deep clone function. Or if you have a 1 level deep object, you could use `let objectCopy = {...objectName}`

Comment: @AlexHoffman - Good point :) the object spread seems a good option or maybe `var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);` might do the trick as well

Comment: Yeah but where do I do that?

Comment: Can you show you code, then we can show you?

Comment: I just added an example. One thing I have thought of is added a computed prop to copy value. Will try that just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a copy via a computed property works. If the value changes then a new copy will be made. Much easier than copying everything into data and having to watch value for changes.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="copy.indoor" @change="onChange"/> Indoor</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="copy.outdoor" @change="onChange"/> Outdoor</label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'OptionsInput',

        props: {
            value: Object, // has indoor, outdoor properties
        },

        computed: {
            copy() { return  {...this.value} }
        },

        methods: {
            onChange() { this.$emit('input', this.copy) }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below when the component instance is created the `clone` object will retain the initial content of `value`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-checkbox label="Indoor" v-model="clone.indoor" @change="onChange"/>
    <v-checkbox label="Outdoor" v-model="clone.outdoor" @change="onChange"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'OptionsInput',

    props: {
      value: Object, // has indoor, outdoor properties
    },

    data () {
       return {
          clone: Object.assign({}, this.value)
       }
    },

    methods: {
      onChange() { this.$emit('input', this.clone) }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This will still modify the input value object which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change bweteen copy&paste the `v-model` to use `clone.indoor`, etc and emitting the clone object instead of the value object. Will edit the example :)

Comment: You also watch 'value' and update data when it changes. Thats the bit I don't like about this solution. You end up with essentially the same code in 2 places.